# Advice to chain several CUDA operations in openCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

I want to :

1. Upload data to CUDA world
2. Do several CUDA operations (gemm, thresholding, dft, etc)
3. Download the result to CPU world

How can I optimize the CUDA block part the best way
Is there a way to call .cu code ?

Here's an example of what I'm doing

```
cv::cuda::GpuMat _emptyGpuMat;
cv::cuda::GpuMat _resultGPU;
cv::cuda::Stream GPUstream;

// -----------------------------
// Upload CPU data to the GPU
// -----------------------------
_mat1GPU.upload(_mat1);
_mat2GPU.upload(_mat2);
const auto _startTimeGPU = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    
// to show several things done in a block of CUDA operations
{
    cv::cuda::gemm(_mat1GPU, _mat2GPU, 1.0, _emptyGpuMat, 0.0, _resultGPU,0, GPUstream);
    cv::cuda::threshold(_mat2GPU, _mat2GPU, .01, std::numeric_limits<double>::max(), cv::THRESH_TOZERO);
}

GPUstream.waitForCompletion();

// -----------------------------
// Download GPU data to the CPU
// -----------------------------
cv::Mat _matResult;
_resultGPU.download(_matResult);
(void)_matResult;

// ---------------------------------------------------------------
// Deallocate data here, otherwise deallocation will be performed
// after context is extracted from the stack
// ---------------------------------------------------------------
_mat1GPU.release();
_mat2GPU.release();
_resultGPU.release();
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you are doing things in the right way. OpenCV developers are using cuBLAS internally for gemm, unless you are searching for a few microseconds no need to search how to call kernels directly.

I'll add one or two things,

1. I've observed the first calls to gpu code are longer than the next ones (probably due to initialisation overhead), I usually perform one or two operations first to let opencv initialize correctly and only then benchmark my code.
2. When using streams, do not forget to use them at every call (Stream is missing on the threshold operation) to ensure the correct execution order for your operations. You may also use cv::Stream when copying data to the GPU if performance matters on these operations too.
3. If you have any doubt on performance, you can use nsight system to benchmark your code and ensure the operations are executed in the same stream, and there is no unneeded synchronisation. (see [NSight system](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-systems) for more informations)

If you really performance enthusiast and need these few microseconds, maybe you can try to have a look at [NVidia Performance primitive](https://developer.nvidia.com/npp) or [cublas](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html) directly to see if this can improve performance but i really doubt on this.

Comment: thanks for your answer and for the advice to use the stream everywhere (good point). I think that for the sake of readability, it's better to write it this way, rather than to go deep into cuBlas primitives (cublasDgemm_v2 in my case, but without cublasDestroy_v2 at each process cycle).

Comment: your idea to "warm up" because the first calls are longer is good also. Thanks for the advice